# Is there a way to update "updatedAt" field on soft delete?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

For one of my models/tables, I have a soft delete defined in Sequelize by setting the `paranoid` option to `true`, which gives me a `deletedAt` column.

I also want to make sure that the `updatedAt` column is always up-to-date as well. Is there a way for the `updatedAt` column to be updated on every change to `deletedAt`? I do want to keep `paranoid` as `true`.

I've investigated using Sequelize hooks: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/hooks.html and I'm assuming it must be one of `afterUpdate` or `afterDestroy`?

Edited to add model if it helps:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => sequelize.define('myTable', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: true,
  },

  /* some more fields... */
  
  deletedAt: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    allowNull: true,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  updatedAt: { // <- want this to reflect updates on deletedAt too
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    allowNull: false,
  },
}, {
  paranoid: true,
  timestamps: true,
  /* Added the following: */
  hooks: {
    afterBulkDestroy(item) {
      console.log(item);
    }
  }
});
```

UDPATE: tried adding in `afterBulkDestroy` which, after printing out `item` shows:

```
{
  where: { id: '12' },
  hooks: true,
  individualHooks: false,
  force: false,
  cascade: false,
  restartIdentity: false,
  type: 'BULKDELETE',
  model: myTable
}
```

Not sure where to go from here - thought I could do a simple `item.updatedAt = item.deletedAt` but obviously not the case.

EDIT:
see Kris' [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70273699/is-there-a-way-to-update-updatedat-field-on-soft-delete/74136266?noredirect=1#comment131581822_74136266) for a nice solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a not-so-elegant but working way of doing it. It's not as easy to manually set `updatedAt` as with user-defined columns, and the `afterDestroy` and `beforeDestroy` hooks require `save()` or `update()` to be able to actually make changes - guess they weren't really designed with being able to update fields in mind.

Solution was:

```
hooks: {
  afterDestroy: async (instance) => {
    instance.changed('updatedAt', true);
    await instance.save();
  }
}
```

Edited - extra note: calling `.changed()` to set `updatedAt` to the value of `deletedAt` is not possible because at the time of both `beforeDestroy` and `afterDestroy`, `deletedAt` still has a value of `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Following up out of curiosity... Can you not do something like the below to update the value of `deletedAt` for the hook?:

```js
hooks: {
    afterDestroy: async (instance, options) => {
        instance.deletedAt = new Date().toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/g, '');
        await instance.save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for delayed reply. It's been a few months since I've worked with Sequelize now, but this looks like it should work! Either way, updating it definitely needs some manual work

Comment: I tried it and it worked for me. Just need to put `individualHooks: true` as a model qeury option in addition to make things work.